# Words for strong or weak rain (sprinkling, drizzling, pouring)

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario, tiempo-meteorológico

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50008/what-kind-of-rain-is-sprinkles) on English.StackExchange made me wonder about words for rain in Spanish. In English, a light rain can be a *drizzle*, *sprinkle*, or *mist* and a heavy rain can be a *deluge*, *downpour*, or *pouring rain*.

What similar words in Spanish are used to describe different types of rainfall?

Comment: Garúa: un americanismo sorprendentemente extendido http://www.terapiatanguera.com.ar/Grandes%20Tangos/Garua.htm

Comment: And here the lyrics of the awesome tango "garúa" http://www.todotango.com/Spanish/las_obras/Tema.aspx?id=x2Ev59LkLTs=

Comment: I've never heard garúa in Spanish, but it is certainly used in Basque.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Click the nouns to view the definition on the RAE:

- *[Llovizna](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=llovizna)*: the correspondent for "drizzle", a "weak" rain;
- *[Aguacero](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=aguacero)*: abundant, sudden rain, that lasts for a short time;
- *[Chubasco](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=chubasco)*: like "downpour", same as aguacero and chaparrón;
- *[Chaparrón](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=chaparr%C3%B3n)*: "tough" rain that lasts for a short time;
- *[Diluvio](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=diluvio)*: Very strong rain, or "flood";

See this page on [Spanish.about.com](http://spanish.about.com/cs/vocabulary/a/weathervocab.htm) for more weather-related terms.

Comment: *diluvio* literally means *deluge*.

Comment: Two words for llovizna: [calabobos](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=calabobos) (literally, fool-drencher, because it looks like it's raining just a little bit, but you end up completely wet) and [sirimiri](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=sirimiri) (used in the Basque Country)

Comment: I had forgotten [jarrear](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=jarrear) for "to rain heavily". Also, "[caer chuzos](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=chuzo)" or "caer chuzos de punta".

Comment: Does anyone know what ‘está sisniendo’ means in this context? I suspect mis-spelling on the part of the person who wrote it to me; he explained he meant ‘lloviendo suave’ but I haven’t been able to track down what ‘sisniendo’ might actually be. He’s Cuban, if that helps

Answer (score 2):

Two colloquial phrases from Costa Rica I recently learned from spanishpod101 are related to this:

> Son pelitos de gato nada mas

Translates to: "It's just little cat hairs". Meaning it's only light rain/drizzle

> San Pedro esta corriendo los muebles

Translates to "St Peter is moving the furniture around". Meaning there is a big storm.

Here is the link to the podcast:
http://www.spanishpod101.com/2008/06/10/regional-spanish-series-61-costa-rican-18-st-peters-moving-the-furniture/

Please note: I am not specifically intending to promote this website. If anyone feels it is not appropriate to link to sites like this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

For light rain 'chispeando' (from 'chispa' = spark) can be used, altho I think it's probably more slang than an actual word.

Comment: [chispear is in the dictionary](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=chispear) and it doesn't say it's colloquial or anything

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple more:

**chipi chipi** (Mexico): a faint drizzle; *example*: --¿Está lloviendo?  --Nomás está chipi chipi.

**neblina**: mist